# Observable.map thrown error not getting caught in subscribe

Tags: java, rx-java, project-reactor

Here's the code:

```
public void initiateProcess() {

findAbandonedOpenOrders() //returns Observable<AsyncN1QueryResult>
    .flatMap(results -> results.rows())
    .map(row -> row.value())
    .map(s -> processStringToGetOrderId(s.toString()))
    .map(
        o -> {
          log.info("Generating access token for orderId: {}", o);
          return identityConnector
              .getServiceTokenFromIdentity()
              .map(
                  issueToken ->
                      RequestInputModel.builder()
                          .authorisationToken(issueToken.getAccessToken())
                          .orderId(o)
                          .build())
              .map(
                  requestInputModel -> {
                    log.info(
                        "Invoking cancel order for orderId: {}",
                        requestInputModel.getOrderId());
                    return cancelOrderApiConnector
                        .invokeAPI(
                            requestInputModel,
                            RequestInputModel.RequestBodyModel.builder().build())  //throw RuntimeException as soon as the flow enters this method
                        .subscribe();
                  })
              .subscribe();
        })
    .subscribe(
        s -> {},
        e -> {
          log.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        });
  }
```

As soon as I call `cancelOrderApiConnector.invokeAPI`, it throws a runtime exception. So, the immediate map should throw it, which should in turn be thrown by the outermost map. But it is not happening. The stack trace won't get printed (logic is implemented in subscribe).

Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You are subscribing in a handler which makes it completely disconnected from its surrounding flows. Please read this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependent-sub-flows

Comment: @akarnokd I read that and unfortunately, have not been able to full grasp it I think. Could you please elaborate on what you just said? Just started with RX.

Comment: You have multiple `subscribe()` operators. The most interior ones do not handle errors. There is also no point to  having those `subscribe()` operations, as they break the observer chain.

Answer (score 1):

Don't break the reactive chain, replace these `map(v -> codeThatProduceAFlux.subscribe())` with `flatMap(v -> codeThatProduceAFlux)` and errors will correctly propagate between sub-steps